# Is there a way to bypass a check policy on Azure DevOps Server for deployment to environment?

Tags: continuous-deployment, azure-devops-pipelines

Currently in my CI/CD pipeline on Azure DevOps Server I'm taking advance approvals for the production stage scheduled to run in future using a business hour check and an approval on the same resource. The deployment correctly starts in the next scheduled window after approvals are complete. There are times though I would want to bypass the business hour check for not having to wait the next time window in order to deploy my resource. Is there any way to accomplish this?

[Approvals and checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvByq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was made available in [Sprint 230](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-230-update#bypass-approvals-and-checks), November 2023. Administrators will now see a "Bypass check" option on pipelines.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of where this is available?  I am not seeing the option, or maybe I am loking in the wrong spot

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this feature is not available. You can check [Ability for environment admin to override environment approval or check](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-for-environment-admin-to-override-environm/1082269).

You can [suggest a feature to the team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).